# Ошибка Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Пытаюсь разобраться в Spring Security, читаю Spring в действии и пробую реализовать код используя аннотации.
При запуске приложения выходит ошибка - Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'.

Понимаю что это связано с WEB.XML, я прописываю фильтры там. Но как обойтись без него? Если не в XML ошибка тогда просьба подсказать где? Заранее спасибо.

Application Context Config:

```
public class WebAppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext){
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(SpringConfig.class, WebConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
        context.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Файл конфигурации:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import({SpringConfig.class})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, true FROM spitter WHERE username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, 'ROLE_SPITTER' FROM spitter WHERE username = ?");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll();

    http
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout");
}
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class SecurityController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(Model model){
    return "login";
}
}
```

Login.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login page.</title>
</head>
<body>
<t:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl" />
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
<h3>Login:</h3>
<br><input type="text" name="j_username">
<h3>Password:</h3>
<br><input type="password" name="j_password">
<br><input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код ошибки:

```
17-Nov-2018 15:17:04.702 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 

org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Nov-2018 15:17:04.936 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
17-Nov-2018 15:17:07.469 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
17-Nov-2018 15:17:07.474 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport.permitAll(PermitAllSupport.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport.permitAll(PermitAllSupport.java:36)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.init(LogoutConfigurer.java:275)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.init(LogoutConfigurer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:294)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47433c6d.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47433c6d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a17ef8eb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47433c6d.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
[2018-11-17 03:17:07,501] Artifact spitter:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
```

Comment: Если расширять класс AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer то Spring ругается на строку ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока видимо рано углубляться в такие дебри, просто подгрузил ConfigSpring через @ImportResource({"classpath:springSecurityConfig.xml"}) и вместе с ним ка не странно заработал  в web.xml.